# super considered super, dependency injection via inheritance in python

Tags: python, testing, dependencies, inversion-of-control, super

So, I have watched Raymond Hettinger's presentation **super considered super** and the ability to leverage dependency injection using super and multiple inheritance https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo

In one of his examples he is showing us how he'd mock a dependency by introducing a mock implementation of a base class and use this mock in a new childclass implementation in order to provide testability:

```
class Robot(object):
   def left(self):
      print("walking left")
   def right(self):
      print("walking right")

class MyRobot(Robot):
   def clean(self):
      super().left()
      super().right()
```

Now, in order to test MyRobot independently of the implementation of Robot, one should, according to his presentation, provide a mock implementation of *Robot* and use this in a new Testable class

```
class MockRobot(Robot):
   def left(self):
      print("mock left")
   def right(self):
      print("mock right")

class MyRobotTestable(MyRobot, MockRobot):
   pass
```

I understand how Method Resolution Order allows us to use the methods of MockRobot in the new testable class.

To be honest, I don't think of this as a good solution, since I am not testing my actual code on top of that I am introducing a new *"class"*, yet only for the reason to make another class testable.

Coming from other OOP languages: Is there any reason, not to inject the dependency via the constructor?

i.e.:

```
class MyRobot(object):
   def __init__(robot):
      self.robot = robot

   def clean(self):
      self.robot.left()
      self.robot.right()
```

I don't need any additional class to provide testability (apart from the mock) and I can inject whatever implementation I want.

I consider this proper OOP following the Dependency Inversion rule.

Comment: What if you want to inherit from multiple classes that implement the same function?

Comment: For example, Django views use a lot of "mixin" classes that override a lot of the same methods. By combining all of these "mixins" you can get some quite complex behaviour and very complex `__mro__`s that your example couldn't replicate. Here's an example of the django rest framework's view inheritance https://i.redd.it/ve66iak6gxm11.png

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I agree, mixins are powerful in that certain manner. I am asking whether this is the right way to deal with Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control. Testability would become a complex thing in my opinion, if one follows the suggestion to introduce a new fake test class, which isn't my actual test class. I feel like violating the Dependency Inversion, knowing the behaviour of an interface, rather than dealing with it as a such.

Answer (score 0):

The difference with classic dependency injection is that the main program instanciating `MyRobot` would have to explicitly provide the dependancy on `Robot` class, passing it as argument in the constructor. Or you could create a factory providing the dependency and the main program would call the factory.

With dependency injection using `super()`, the dependency on `Robot` is transparent, but you can still overwrite it for testing purposes. I guess this is a more pythonic way of doing dependency injection.